# dowload file from shared drive to desktop C#

Tags: c#, file-upload

I'm trying to download a file from shared drive to desktop but it keeps throwing an error that its not a virtual path. Here is my code:

```
if (Directory.Exists(Server.MapPath("M://SharedDrive//" +  username)))
{
   File.Copy("M://SharedDrive//" + username, "C:\\Documents and Settings\\user\\Desktop\\" + username, true);
}
```

Comment: It's not a valid path either... walk through your code above in the debugger and see what is actually being sent as the first parameter to `File.Copy`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you doing this from in an ASP.NET application? (I'm guessing since you are using `Server.MapPath`). Then you have two problems:

1. IIS runs in the service session, which has no access to the users' mapped drives such as `M:`. IIS can only access physical drives, or UNC paths (the latter requires security to be set up correctly).
2. IIS has no access to a user's desktop.

Please explain a bit more detailed what you are trying to achieve if we are to be able to help.

Comment: yes it is the mapping of the drive that is the issue. thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

If you copy file to/from network location, you should login or impersonate user.

Check these;

- [Copy file on a network shared drive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1432213/copy-file-on-a-network-shared-drive)
- http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/csharpgeneral/thread/ffebef9c-a063-46e6-8307-2f73bbf688b7/