# Create files in the shared folder using the ip address

Tags: c#, wpf, server-side, shared

Need suggestion to design an application

i have planned to write a c# WPF application. where i will configure all the static ip address of the servers. my application will create some log files and write to the shared folder of the corresponding servers.

How can i design my standalone application which will write the files to shared folder

Comment: i wanted to create files in the shared folder using the ipaddress

Comment: And what is your **problem** with that task? You still haven't told us that!

Comment: the problem is i gone through the sockets, it need my application as server and all the configured ip address should have client to transfer or create the files, but i just want to do without client

Comment: a standalone application which will create files in the shared folder

Answer (score 2):

You can. Just use System.IO.File.Create(@"//127.0.0.1/Share/file.txt"); You'll probably run into permission problems, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1432213/copy-file-on-a-network-shared-drive) is a link to a solution.

Answer (score -2):

number = int(input("Enter a number: "))
factorial = 1

if number < 0: print("Factorial is not defined for negative numbers.") elif number == 0: print("The factorial of 0 is 1.") else: for i in range(1, number + 1): factorial *= i print("The factorial of", number, "is", factorial)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34746865)