# Socket listener does not work on startup

Tags: c#, sockets, udp

I have created a socket listener which reads data from the specific port and works fine if I run this application clicking on exe. But when it runs from window startup then socket listener can not read data from socket.

Following code is in **Form1_Load** function

```
UdpClient udpClient = new UdpClient(8010);
while (true)
{
    IPEndPoint RemoteIpEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 0);
    Byte[] receiveBytes = udpClient.Receive(ref RemoteIpEndPoint);
    string returnData = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(receiveBytes);

}
```

Comment: I'm sure that sometime while asking your almost 60 questions you've come along [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1432213/copy-file-on-a-network-shared-drive). "socket listener can not listen" is not a proper problem description.

Comment: Your edit does not help much. Why can't it read data? Does it hang? Throw an exception? Return an empty byte array? Why do you do a `while (true)` in the Form_Load event handler anyway?

Comment: What do you mean by window startup ? Is it a service or is it executed before or after user login ?

Comment: It executes after user login.

Comment: If you run the command "netstat -a -p UDP -b",  are you listening on port 8010?

Comment: Yes listening on port 8010

Comment: What happens if you insert a System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100)  in the while loop ?