# How to Authenticate network credentials to create a file in shared path

Tags: acumatica

I am trying to create a file in a shared folder with authenticating the network credentials. How can i do it with in acumatica framework?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With Acumatica Framework you're not restricted to use only the components provided by Acumatica, but have the entire .Net Framework toolset to fill the gaps and address scenarios, which are not very common for Acumatica Framework.

I believe there should be a ton of information and C# code samples to address your scenario on StackOverflow and across the internet, like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38704825/3929852).

Comment: Thanks for the link.