# How to move a file exists into shared directory to another folder in c#

Tags: c#, file-move, shared-directory

I have a C# code that moves a local file from folder to another following the code below:

```
 File.Move("C:\folder1\file.txt","C:\folder1\folder2\");
```

this code moves the file.txt to folder2
my problem is the file.txt exists on a shared directory so i need to access it and move it to second folder like this

```
 File.Move("\\shared directory\\folder1\\file.txt","\\shared directory\\folder2\\");
```

the code above didnt
 works any solution?

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1432213/copy-file-on-a-network-shared-drive

Comment: Have you tried mapping the two shared folders to have drive letters in WIndows? so that `\\shared directory\\folder1` is `S:\\` and `\\shared directory\\folder2` is `T:\\`

Answer (score 0):

Try mapping the shared network drives to drive letters in Windows:

1. Open Computer (`[Win]+[E]`)
2. Click the 'Computer' tab from the top ribbon
3. Select the 'Map Network Drive'
4. Select a drive letter and enter the first shared folder path(`\\shared directory\folder1`)
5. Keep 'Reconnect at sign-in' checked if needed
6. If you need to log in to access the shared folder with an account that is different to your windows login, check the `Connect using different credentials` box and enter the credentials when prompted.
7. Repeat for `\\shared directory\\folder2` selecting a different drive letter

From there you should be able to use the same code you mentioned was working:

```
File.Move("S:\file.txt","T:\");
```

Assuming `S:\` is mapped to `\\shared directory\folder1` and `T:\` is mapped to `\\shared directory\folder2\`

Comment: Could not find file 'A:\file.txt'

Answer (score 0):

Try
`File.Move(@"\\shared directory\folder1\file.txt", @"\\shared directory\folder2\");`

Comment: It's apparent that there's a file share issue.  Are you sure that you are running the program as a user with access to the network share?  If running as Admin, admin will need access rights to that share as well.