# How to download file from server to shared network folder?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, directory

I have .exe program and i can easly can download my files from server to local path with my code below

```
    if (!Directory.Exists(downurl))//i'm checking directory is exist
    {
         Directory.CreateDirectory(downurl);
    }
    Uri uri = new Uri(filepath);
    string path = downurl + filename;
    webClient.DownloadFileCompleted += (sender, e);
    webClient.DownloadFileAsync(uri, path); //downloading file async...
```

But when i try to download file to shared network folder i cannot download image

when i wrote directory address like this `\\ip\\folder\\folder\\file.txt` my code cannot find directory

when i wrote directory address like this `ip\\folder\\folder\\file.txt` my code works fine but cannot see file in folder

Dow you have any idea on this ?

Thanks

Comment: maybe this can help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1432259/13687491

Comment: Yes i saw that solution but i need download because i coded all algorithm on that